# Async task method returns right after one of it await tasks executed without proceeding to next task

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, microsoft-graph-api

My project is ASP.NET MVC running on .NET 4.7.2. A controller action method calls a chain of methods. One of the methods is calling the Microsoft Graph API built-in async method. When the method executes, it returns quickly with the process of rest of the code.

Below is the code when

```
result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
```

executes and returns.

```
public string AddRequest(List<names> collections)
{   
    // removed some code here
    email.SendEmailSimpleEmail();    
}

public  async Task SendEmailSimpleEmail()
{
    // var token = await GetGraphAccessToken();
    // With client credentials flows

    var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
       .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
       //.WithTenantId(tenant)
       .WithAuthority(authority)
       .Build();

    string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    AuthenticationResult result = null;

    try
    {
        result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
          new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
              async (requestMessage) =>
              {
                  requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                      new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
              }));
    // removed the rest of the code and also the try and catch block too
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `Task.Delay{10000)` to do. You have to await all awaitables.

Comment: Paulo, I was just testing it.  I am going to remove it.  when the process hit the await.app.AcquireToken it never gets to next lines of code and return from there. I have several try and catch, even I don't see an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All *awaitables* need to be awaited.

In an asynchronous method, the code runs synchronously until the first `await` of a non-completed *awaitable*.

That's what happens when the execution reaches the invocation of `app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync()`.

Because that *awaitable* hasn't completed, the execution of that method is interrupted and the control is returned to the invoking method.

Because the invoking method (`AddRequest`) is not awaiting the `Task` returned by `SendEmailSimpleEmail`, the execution continues, and the execution exits `AddRequest`.

Comment: but why the rest of the code ran after app.AcquireTokenForClient was in await.  There is another await function in the same method.

Comment: The code might have always run. I just couldn't see the result when you expected and couldn't step into it.